# does cout before return statement of recursive function stops it?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

Here, the return statement don't get call if i call cout function before of it.

```
int factorial(int n){
 if(n>=2)
   cout<<"number of times the function called: "<<endl;
 return n*factorial(n-1);
       }
```

I expect it should be returning the value in last 
the hole code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int factorial(int n){
  if(n>=2)

  cout<<"number of times the loop executed: "<<n-1 <<endl;
   return n*factorial(n-1);

   }
  int main(){
  int number;
  cout<<"enter the number whose factorial is to be calculated..:"<<endl;
  cin>>number;
  int result=factorial(number);
  cout<<"factorial is: "<<result<<endl;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of an `if`-statement can be either a compound statement, which is a list of statements surrounded by `{}`, or it is the *single statement* following the `if`'s condition. That means that this code:

```
if(n>=2)
    cout<<"number of times the function called: "<<endl;
    return n*factorial(n-1);
```

is completely equivalent to:

```
if(n>=2){
    cout<<"number of times the function called: "<<endl;
}
return n*factorial(n-1);
```

You probably intended the following:

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(n>=2){
        cout<<"number of times the function called: "<<endl;
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
    return 1; // you should ALWAYS return something from a non-void function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to terminate your recursion with something like this:

```
return (n == 0 || n == 1) ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1);
```

Comment: Someone struggling with `if` and `return` most likely won't be accustomed with the ternary operator.